# How to create a MySQL view

Tags: mysql, sql, cross-join

I have MySQL visits table as

```
visit_date        client_id
2019-01-01 08-00-00 1
2019-01-01 11-00-00 2
```

**work_hours** table  as

```
hour    name
8        '08-00'
9        '09-00'
...
18        '18-00'
```

and tables **clients** as

```
  client_id client_name
  1           aaa
  2           bbb 
  3           ccc
```

How to create a view to get data?

```
client_id   hour_name    count
1        '08-00'    1
1        '09-00'    0   
.....
1        '18-00'    0
2        '08-00'    0
2        '09-00'    0
2        '10-00'    0
2        '11-00'    1
2        '12-00'    0
.....
2        '18-00'    0
3        '08-00'    0
3        '09-00'    0
.....    all zero
3        '18-00'    0
```

Comment: If a client has no visit, do you want him in your result set?

Comment: yes, with zero result

Comment: Check my answer, I've added a SQL Fiddle example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT c.client_id, w.hour_name,
    (SELECT COUNT(1) 
    FROM visits v
    WHERE v.client_id = c.client_id
    AND HOUR(v.visit_date) = w.hour) as tot_visit
FROM clients c
CROSS JOIN work_hours w
ORDER BY c.client_id, w.hour_name
```

See [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/99dccd/3/0)

Comment: instead of  "ORDER BY c.client_id, w.hour_name"
may be "Group BY c.client_id, w.hour_name" . In that case query returns  same result as in my answer. 
Thanks for your answer!

Comment: @harp1814: GROUP BY in your query is unuseful because you have no aggregate function and the cardinality is one for each couple (client id, hour name). With ORDER BY you have the right order (you have requested on your question)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT c.client_id,
       wh.hour_name,

  (SELECT count(1)
   FROM visits
   WHERE hour(visit_date) = wh.hour
     AND client_id=c.client_id) AS chcount
FROM work_hours wh,
     clients c;
```